# Display gitlab-ci pipeline status and runner not really displaying anything

Tags: python, json, gitlab-ci

Hey guys the task I have at hand is to write a python program that checks a Gitlab CI pipeline's status and the runner it's using and to print them out. It is pretty much my first attempt at python so my mistake might be extremely trivial but those are also often that most difficult issues to troubleshoot so I'd be glad if someone can point out what I've done incorrectly.

```
import requests
import subprocess
import json

res = requests.get('https://git.censored.com/censored/Test33004__half/pipelines')
json_data = json.loads(res.text)

if element['status'] == "active"
    print element['status']
    print element['runner']
else
    print element['status']
```

Comment: what is the content of requests.get('...'), json I suppose?

Comment: Yeah, it's json similar to the examples here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html

Comment: Then you just need to check if the json has the required key:

if element['status'] and element['runner']:
   ...
else:
    ..

Comment: you are missing colon : after the if and else